# Removing a decimal point from a number and converting it to a whole number in PHP

Tags: php

I have a small issue....

I have a php function which is generating a number based on dividing two whole numbers. This will always be expressed as a percentage of 1.

eg, my function would generate a number such as 0.3 or 0.01222 or 0.23

I need to convert this percentage to a whole number number as a part of 100 with three digits.

so 0.3 would become 030, 0.01222 would become 001 and 1 would become 100

Is there a simple way to do this in PHP?

Cheers :)

Comment: do you also need 0s at left? why?

Comment: Yeah I need the end result to be a specific length.

Answer (score 4):

The end-result will no longer be a number but more a string, so just go with string operations:

```
$number = 0.3;

// Multiply by 100 and remove stuff after decimal point
$string = (string) floor($number * 100);

// Add zeros until the string has a total length of three characters
$string = str_pad($string, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
$num = 0.01222;
$num2 = ceil($num * 100);
```

Comment: Hi Bfavaretto. That outputs "1" I would need it to output as "001" Is there a way to get it to look like this?

Comment: substr('00'.floor($number*100),-3,3);